# How to compute standard errors of an estimator with antithetic variates?

Tags: standard-error, monte-carlo, finance

I'm pricing American options using Longstaff and Schwartz Least square method.

When using the following Python code, I obtain nearly the same prices and standard errors as in the *Valuing American Options by Simulation:
A Simple Least-Squares Approach* Longstaff and Schwartz (2001):

```py
    import numpy as np
    import numpy.random as npr
    import warnings
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
    from numpy.polynomial.laguerre import lagfit, 
         lagval
    
    # Same parameters as in the original paper
    class par: pass
    par.S0 = 36
    par.K = 40
    par.r = 0.06
    par.sigma = 0.2
    par.T = 1.0
    par.I = 100000
    par.M = 50
    
    def gen_sn(par,anti_path):
        ''' Function to generate random numbers for 
            simulation.
        Parameters
        ==========
        M : int
        number of time intervals for discretization
        I : int
        number of paths to be simulated
        '''
        np.random.seed(1)
        if anti_path is True:
            sn = npr.standard_normal((par.M + 1, 
            par.I//2))
        else:
            sn = npr.standard_normal((par.M + 1, 
                 par.I))
        return sn
    
    def gbm_mcs_amer(par):
        ''' Valuation of American option in Black-
            Scholes-Merton
        by Monte Carlo simulation by LS algorithm. 
        Parameters
        ==========
        S0 : spot price
        K : strike float
        r : riskless interest rate
        I : int, number of paths to be simulated
        T : time to maturity, in years
        M : int, number of time intervals for  
             discretization
        sigma : vol
        Returns
        =======
        C0 : float
        estimated present value of American call 
          option
        '''
        dt = par.T / par.M 
        df = np.exp(-par.r * dt) # discount function
    
        # Generation of underlying asset process
        # Stock Price Paths
        S = par.S0 * np.exp(np.cumsum((par.r - 0.5 * par.sigma ** 2) * 
               dt + par.sigma * np.sqrt(dt) * sn, axis=0)) # by 
                    exponentiating the Brownian motion
        S[0] = par.S0 # Initiliazing underlying path
        
        # put option pay-off
        h = np.maximum(par.K - S, 0)
        # LS algorithm
        V = np.copy(h)
        for t in range(par.M - 1, 0, -1):
            reg = lagfit(S[t], V[t + 1] * df, 10)
            C = lagval(S[t], reg)
            V[t] = np.where(C > h[t], V[t + 1] * df, h[t])
            
            # MCS estimator
            y_i = df * V[1]
            C0 = np.mean(y_i)
            SE = np.std(y_i) / np.sqrt(par.I)
        
        return C0, SE
    # Regular Estimate loop
    sn = gen_sn(par,False)
        
    print("Reg","T:",par.T,"sigma:",par.sigma)
    for par.S0 in range(36,44+1,2):
        print("S0:",par.S0,"Price,SE:",gbm_mcs_amer_reg(par)[0],gbm_mcs_amer_reg(par)[1])
```

I then attempt implementing antithetic variates price as Glasserman proposes [Antithetic paths estimator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXkOF.png) and the standard error as Boyle and Glasserman proposes [Antithetic paths standard error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYguU.png):

```py
    def gbm_mcs_amer_AP(par):
    dt = par.T / par.M 
    df = np.exp(-par.r * dt) # discount function

    # Generation of underlying asset process
    # Stock Price Paths
    S = par.S0 * np.exp(np.cumsum((par.r - 0.5 * par.sigma ** 2) * dt
    + par.sigma * np.sqrt(dt) * sn , axis=0)) 
    # by exponentiating the Brownian motion
    S[0] = par.S0
    S1 = par.S0 * np.exp(np.cumsum((par.r - 0.5 * par.sigma ** 2) * dt
    + par.sigma * np.sqrt(dt) * -sn , axis=0)) # Antithetic paths
    S1[0] = par.S0
    
    # put option pay-off
    h = np.maximum(par.K - S, 0)
    h1 = np.maximum(par.K - S1, 0)
    # LS algorithm
    V = np.copy(h)
    V1 = np.copy(h1)
    for t in range(par.M - 1, 0, -1):
        reg = lagfit(S[t], V[t + 1] * df, 10)
        C = lagval(S[t], reg)
        V[t] = np.where(C > h[t], V[t + 1] * df, h[t])
        reg1 = lagfit(S1[t], V1[t + 1] * df, 10)
        C1 = lagval(S1[t], reg1)
        V1[t] = np.where(C1 > h1[t], V1[t + 1] * df, h1[t])
        
        # MCS estimator
        y_i = df * (V[1]+V1[1])/2 # avg. pairs
        C0 = np.mean(y_i)
        SE = np.std(y_i) / np.sqrt(par.I) # Sample std. dev. of avg. pairs
    
    return C0, SE
      
    # AP Estimate loop
    sn = gen_sn(par,True)
    
    print("AP","T:",par.T,"sigma:",par.sigma)
    for par.S0 in range(36,44+1,2):
        print("S0:",par.S0,"Price,SE:",gbm_mcs_amer_AP(par)[0],gbm_mcs_amer_AP(par)[1])
```

The antithetic variate prices are close to the prices in the Longstaff and Schwartz paper, but the standard errors seem to be too small, as they reduce more variance than a control variate and matching two moments in the random number generation.

Comment: This *might* be a good fit for [Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange](https://quant.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you